# A custom table using TikZ instead of tabular

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables, tabularx, tikz-styles, pgfplotstable

How could I create a table like below using TikZ? I tried using `matrix`, but could not get rid of few table lines like below.

[image]

It might be easier in `tabular` LaTeX, but I want in TikZ because I could then have embedded output in jupyter notebook using `tikzmagic`.

**Update:**
Here is my MWE not working

```
\documentclass[table]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots, pgfplotstable}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, positioning}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\tikzset{%
square matrix/.style={
    matrix of nodes,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth, row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
    nodes in empty cells,
    nodes={draw,
      minimum size=#1,
      anchor=center,
      align=center,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
},
  square matrix/.default=0.9cm
}
\newcommand{\tx}{|[fill=cyan!20]|}
\newcommand{\tb}{|[fill=yellow!20]|}
\newcommand{\tg}{|[fill=gray!20]|}

\matrix[square matrix] (A)
{
$p(x,y)$    &       & 0     & 100   & 200 \\
x           & 100   & 0.20  & 0.10  & 0.20 \\
};

        \node[below=0.50cm,align=center,text width=5cm] at (0,-3)
        {
            A sample joint pmf
        };

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

**Output I get:**

[image]

**Update:**
Thanks to @marmot, I am able to achieve and also draw two more on right side, however having a feeling that the table lines on new two tables on right are not exactly straight.

**Updated MWE:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (table) [matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells]
    {\rho(x,y) & & 0 & 100 & 200\\
     & 100 & .20 & .10 & .20\\
     & 250 & .05 & .15 & .30\\
    };
    \draw ($(table-2-1)!0.5!(table-3-1)$) coordinate (aux)
    (aux.center -| table-1-1.west) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
    \node[above=1pt of table-1-4] {$y$};
    \draw ($(table-2-2.east)!0.5!(table-2-3.west)$) coordinate (aux2)
    (table.north -| aux2) -- (table.south -| aux2);
    \draw ($(table-1-1.south)!0.5!(table-2-2.north)$) coordinate (aux3)
    (table.west |- aux3) -- (table.east |- aux3);

    \matrix (table_x) [%
        right=1cm of table.north east, anchor=north west,
        matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells
    ]
    {x & 100 & 250 \\
     \rho_X(x) & .5 & .5 \\
    };
    \draw ($(table_x-2-1.east)!0!(table_x-1-1.west)$) coordinate (aux4) (table_x.north -| aux4) -- (table_x.south -| aux4);
    \draw ($(table_x-1-1.south)!0.5!(table_x-2-2.north)$) coordinate (aux5) (table_x.west |- aux5) -- (table_x.east |- aux5);

    \matrix (table_y) [%
        right=1cm of table_x.north east, anchor=north west,
        matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells
    ]
    {y & 0 & 100 & 200 \\
     \rho_Y(y) & .25 & .25 & .5 \\
    };
    \draw ($(table_y-2-1.east)!0!(table_y-1-1.west)$) coordinate (aux6) (table_y.north -| aux6) -- (table_y.south -| aux6);
    \draw ($(table_y-1-1.south)!0.5!(table_y-2-2.north)$) coordinate (aux7) (table_y.west |- aux7) -- (table_y.east |- aux7);   

  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output:**
[image]

Comment: Do you want the table in the image or that table without the lines?

Comment: Could you please show us what you've tried? I am particularly surprised about "could not get rid of few table lines".By default, a matrix does not have lines.

Comment: hi marmot, yes I just did.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42491512/display-latex-table-tabular-in-jupyter-with-latex-cell-magic, which suggests https://github.com/mathjax/mathjax-docs/wiki/LaTeX-Tabular-environment.

Answer (score 2):

I do not have any problems in producing such tables with Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (table) [matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells]
    {\rho(x,y) & & 0 & 100 & 200\\
     & 100 & .20 & .10 & .20\\
     & 250 & .05 & .15 & .30\\
    };
    \path ($(table-2-1)!0.5!(table-3-1)$) coordinate (aux)
    (aux.center -| table-1-1.west) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
    \node[above=1pt of table-1-4] {$y$};
    \draw ($(table-2-2.east)!0.5!(table-2-3.west)$) coordinate (aux2)
    (table.north -| aux2) -- (table.south -| aux2);
    \draw ($(table-1-1.south)!0.5!(table-2-2.north)$) coordinate (aux3)
    (table.west |- aux3) -- (table.east |- aux3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or with left-aligned nodes.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[set width/.style={column #1/.style={text width=6mm}}]
    \matrix (table) [matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells,
    set width/.list={2,...,5}]
    {\rho(x,y) & & 0 & 100 & 200\\
     & 100 & .20 & .10 & .20\\
     & 250 & .05 & .15 & .30\\
    };
    \path ($(table-2-1)!0.5!(table-3-1)$) coordinate (aux)
    (aux.center -| table-1-1.west) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
    \node[above=1pt of table-1-4] {$y$};
    \draw ($(table-2-2.east)!0.5!(table-2-3.west)$) coordinate (aux2)
    (table.north -| aux2) -- (table.south -| aux2);
    \draw ($(table-1-1.south)!0.5!(table-2-2.north)$) coordinate (aux3)
    (table.west |- aux3) -- (table.east |- aux3);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**: Answer to your updated question. The horizontal red line is just for illustration, i.e. you don't want to keep it in your document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[every node/.append style={text depth=.25ex,text height=1.5ex}]
    \matrix (table) [matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells]
    {\rho(x,y) & & 0 & 100 & 200\\
      & 100 & .20 & .10 & .20\\
     & 250 & .05 & .15 & .30\\
    };
    \draw ($(table-2-1)!0.5!(table-3-1)$) coordinate (aux)
    (aux.center -| table-1-1.west) node[anchor=west]{$x$};
    \node[above=1pt of table-1-4] {$y$};
    \draw ($(table-2-2.east)!0.5!(table-2-3.west)$) coordinate (aux2)
    (table.north -| aux2) -- (table.south -| aux2);
    \draw ($(table-1-1.south)!0.5!(table-2-2.north)$) coordinate (aux3)
    (table.west |- aux3) -- (table.east |- aux3);

    \matrix (table_x) [%
        right=1cm of table.north east, anchor=north west,
        matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells
    ]
    {x & 100 & 250 \\
     \rho_X(x) & .5 & .5 \\
    };
    \draw ($(table_x-2-1.east)!0!(table_x-1-1.west)$) coordinate (aux4) 
    (table_x.north -| aux4) -- (table_x.south -| aux4);
    \draw ($(table_x-1-1.south)!0.5!(table_x-2-2.north)$) 
    coordinate (aux5) (table_x.west |- aux5) -- (table_x.east |- aux5);

    \matrix (table_y) [%
        right=1cm of table_x.north east, anchor=north west,
        matrix of math nodes,nodes in empty cells
    ]
    {y & 0 & 100 & 200 \\
     \rho_Y(y) & .25 & .25 & .5 \\
    };
    \draw ($(table_y-2-1.east)!0!(table_y-1-1.west)$) 
    coordinate (aux6) (table_y.north -| aux6) -- (table_y.south -| aux6);
    \draw ($(table_y-1-1.south)!0.5!(table_y-2-2.north)$) 
    coordinate (aux7) (table_y.west |- aux7) -- (table_y.east |- aux7);   

  \end{tikzpicture}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
   \draw[red] ([yshift=-5.4cm] current page.north west)
   -- ([yshift=-5.4cm] current page.north east);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I just updated with my MWE marmot.

Comment: there might be few unwanted lines in my MWE, this is because I quickly extracted that part from source document to create a MWE, so might not have isolated all unwanted parts. But I could not figure out which part was adamantly drawing lines around table. It was straightforward and easier using tabular but I want to stick to tikz for better readability in my jupyter notebook.

Comment: what does this line ```($(table-2-1)!0.5!(table-3-1)$) coordinate (aux)``` mean? its defining the aux coordinate? if so what is !0.5!? I infer table-2-1 as 2nd row, 1st column?

Comment: @PaariVendhan The lines come from `draw`, i.e. each node is in a box. Since `$p(x,y)$ ` is wider than the `minimum size` of `9mm`, there are these gaps. They will disappear if you increase the `minimum width` of the first column to become wider than `$p(x,y)$ `.  And yes, `($(table-2-1)!0.5!(table-3-1)$) coordinate (aux)` defines an `aux` coordinate that is used later.

Comment: oh reg lines I asked why they appeared in my MWE, because there was no draw command in my MWE.  reg $p(x,y)$, thats quite a trick. Min size 9mm is default? and i can add more tables side ways? i was going to use qquad to get something like [this](https://i.postimg.cc/0Nn5HD43/image.png)

Comment: @PaariVendhan There is a `draw` command in your MWE: `nodes={draw,`. `\qquad` has no effect in  `tikzpicture`, only in nodes. You can place the next matrix `right of` the previous one to have them side by side. (Play with `anchor`s to have them aligned relative to each other.)

Comment: so if next matrix is say ```matrix (table_x) [right of = table]```? I will use your solution and try to add matrix tables right of them..

Comment: @PaariVendhan Yes, you could do `\matrix (table2) [right=1cm of table,...` in my code. As I said, if you want the matrices top aligned, you need to play with anchors: `\matrix (table2) [right=1cm of table.north east,anchor=north west,...`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85279/discussion-between-paari-vendhan-and-marmot).

Answer (score 1):

a minimalistic solution:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.141592mm]{standalone}  % :)
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,
                 nodes in empty cells,
                 nodes={minimum height=3ex, minimum width=2em,
                        inner sep=0pt, anchor=center},
                 column 1/.style = {nodes={minimum width=3.3em}},
                 ]
    {
    \rho(x,y)   &       & 0     & 100 & 200\\
                & 100   & .20   & .10 & .20\\
                & 250   & .05   & .15 & .30\\
    };
    \draw (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-1-5.south east);
    \draw (m-1-2.north east) -- (m-3-2.south east);
    \node[above] at (m-1-4.north) {$y$};
    \node[right] at (m-2-1.south west) {$x$};
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately the vertical line is not really centered between the cells. That is, why don't you draw it with `\draw (m-1-3.north west) -- (m-3-3.south west);`, or why is the location dependent on this choice? This is why I am using a "less minimalistic" code with `calc`....

Comment: @marmot, nodes are tight aligned, so the lines are almost on the middle between nodes.  small difference  can arise due to `column`/`row sep` value. so you are (as usual) right :-) . this (tiny?) discrepancy is the cost for my "minimalistic" solution ;-). your solution is deep study (some times i use the similar approach in similar cases), so +1 ...

Comment: @marmot, off-topic: do you wake up so early or still not went to slip? here is 04:36 :-(

Comment: +1 also. Here it is 8:37 pm ... almost time to go to bed.